# How can I make a Win32 DLL that is reference-able in a C# application?

Tags: c#, winapi, interop

I have a rather large legacy nmake (Win32) project that creates a static library from native C++ code. I need to use this library in a C#/.Net application.  In the past after much effort I had been successful at wrapping the static library in a managed C++ library, which I am then able to reference in a C#/.Net application.  However, after receiving updates from the developers of the nmake project, and having gone through an many upgrades on my own build machine in the meantime, it is no longer working.

I am however able to import the cpp and header files of the nmake project and build it to a Win32 static library in VS 2010, by setting all of the preprocessor constants in the build properties.  I set the build configuration type to DLL, and then try to add a reference to the Win32 output in my C#/.Net application hoping to use P/Invoke down the road, and it fails with a message "A reference to MyLibrary could not be added."

Is there a way to build the Win32 library so that it can be referenced by the C#/.Net project and so that I can use P/Invoke?

Comment: Uhm, P/Invoke should work with any standard DLL following the Win C conventions .. you *don't* add the reference (because it's *not* a .NET Assembly), but rather just [use Platform Invoke specifying the DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42b9ea93.aspx). Now, you can create a *wrapper* or "interop" .NET library to make these P/Invoke calls, and reference that. Another option is to expose COM, from which PIAs can be "automatically generated".

Comment: You can only use managed libraries as a reference, and you only use P/Invoke for unmanaged libraries.

Comment: I get a similar error if I try to use the DLL directly.  I think they don't specify the Win C conventions in the nmake project.  I'll stick to the wrapper library.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to build the Win32 library so that it can be referenced by the C#/.Net project and so that I can use P/Invoke?

If you want to directly *reference* the library, you'll need to build a C++/CLI project using your library, and make managed wrappers.

If you want to use P/Invoke (which is a separate concept), you can make exports with a C API, and call those directly via P/Invoke.

The two approaches are both valid, but completely different in terms of implementation (C++/CLI vs. C API wrappers) on the native side, as well as used differently (directly referenced for C++/CLI vs. P/Invoke via `[DllImport]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWIG to generate wrappers for your code.  SWIG is a very powerful tool and worth taking the time learn. It creates wrappers for a number of languages including Python, C#, and Java so if you get it working with one language it is fairly easy to use in other languages as well. It will generate all the wrapper code for you, although you will probably need to do some work with type.  You use swig to create a special DLL that SWIG generates code for and then used supplied C# code to access the DLL without needing to deal with managed C++ assemblies which can be a nightmare to deal with.

http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html

Edit: my explanation may not be that clear and the docs are pretty overwhelming, take a look at the "What is swig?" section here to get started:

http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn2